# How to show admob without requesting repeatly?

Tags: android, ios, admob, cocos2d-x

I need to call show/hide frequently, it seems everytime I call show, it requests ad again and can not show quickly. I need to just show last ad quickly, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Banner or interstitial? And what do you mean by show/hide frequently? Show/hide what?

Comment: I only wanna show the banner ad when the player fails the game. so the banner ad is shown/hidden frequently. Every time I call show ad via cocos2d-x admob plugin, it requests new ad and creates new adview, this makes the game paused for a while. I just modified the plugin function to reach my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

For your `adView`, implement `AdListener`

and in

> onReceiveAd(Ad ad)

call

> adView.stopLoading();